# How do I run only first command in backgound?

Tags: command-line

I want to send only first command to run in background. How can I do that?

 For example for this commands

```
sudo apt-get update & && apt-get upgrade
```

My first command must run before second command like above and I don't want to run second command as first. Then above example is really good example since I have to run update command before upgrade.

But it give error(for my real command too):

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

Comment: see if the edit works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both in background:

```
~$ (sleep 1 &) && (sleep 2 &)
~$
```

1st in background

```
~$ (sleep 1 &) && (sleep 2)
~$
```

wont work with apt-get though.

edit: found it.

```
 sudo bash -c 'apt-get update >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown' && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Proof:

```
sudo bash -c 'apt-get update >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown' && sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf libcrypt-blowfish-perl libcrypt-cbc-perl
  libcrypt-rijndael-perl libexpect-perl libgnome2-gconf-perl
  libgtk2-ex-simple-list-perl libgtk2-gladexml-perl libgtk2-unique-perl
  libio-stty-perl libkeybinder0 libnet-arp-perl libnet-pcap-perl
  libnet-proxy-perl libossp-uuid-perl libossp-uuid16 libunique-1.0-0
  libxml-parser-perl python-keybinder
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and the update is still running:

```
~$ ps -ef|grep apt-get
root      6102  1519  1 12:11 pts/0    00:00:00 apt-get update
```

It will break the sequence though: the upgrade will finish before the update.