# Starting program via terminal and putting it immidiatly in the bg / bashrc

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, bashrc

So i am trying to start a Programm by using the terminal but i also dont want it to be locked to the said terminal.

i added an alias inside the bashrc for easy startup:

```
alias tksuite='sudo sh /usr/local/tksuite_client/run_client.sh && ^Z && bg && disown'
```

I also tried this:

```
alias tksuite='sudo sh /usr/local/tksuite_client/run_client.sh  \& && disown'
```

which unfortunally also didn't work or better said, worked but not as i like it to be since the program was not showing, but was running.

Any ideas/pointers where i am going wrong?

Edit: Forgot to mention: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The second alias looks OK, but why escape the `&`? Shouldn't it be just `&`?

Comment: @muru Because i am recieving a Syntax Error, unexpected word &&

Comment: That's because `&&` has no place there. It should just be `sudo sh /usr/local/tksuite_client/run_client.sh & disown`. You can't test the exit value of a backgrounded process, so `&&` is meaningless. Or you can also use `nohup sudo sh /usr/local/tksuite_client/run_client.sh`.

Comment: @muru Changed that, and worked, same result while escaping the &. But now how do i get the program to actually show up?

Comment: For [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540113/starting-program-via-terminal-and-putting-it-immidiatly-in-the-bg-bashrc#comment739127_540113) see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/538894/how-do-i-run-only-first-command-in-backgound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a process to the background works differently than you assume especially in combination with `sudo`. For these reasons I recommend an entirely different approach:

1. Create a shell script `tksuite` in some directory occurring in `$PATH`, e. g. `/usr/bin/tksuite`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /bin/sh /usr/local/tksuite_client/run_client.sh "$@"
   ```
2. Make it executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/tksuite
   ```
3. Now you can start the script with superuser privileges in background with

   ```
   gksudo tksuite & disown
   ```

Alternatively this can all be done in a shell function

```
tksuite() {
    gksudo -- sh /usr/local/tksuite_client/run_client.sh "$@" &
    disown
}
```

invokable with `tksuite` as you intended.

Comment: Thanks for that approach but unfortunally it does not work. when i run sudo -b tksuite it does....nothing. I am not getting any error so i cant tell whats wrong.

Comment: Is tksuite a GUI application? In that case `gksudo tksuite` is better suited for the job.

Comment: yes it is. tried gksudo tksuite, executes without error but still nothing shows up

Comment: What's the output of `sudo which tksuite || echo 'No such command'`?

Comment: Output: /usr/bin/tksuite

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the `run_client.sh` script. I suspect that it doesn't discover its own path correctly through symlinks. Can you please catch the output of `gksudo sh -x /usr/bin/tksuite` and post a link to it in your comment?

Comment: -x not a valid option for gksudo. I expect you dont want the help output...?
I tried with the -d (debug) results here http://pastebin.com/ByL9KMES

Comment: `-x` is to be supplied to `sh`, as per the command in my previous comment: `gksudo sh -x /usr/bin/tksuite`

Comment: gksudo: Ungültige Option -- x // <- Invalid Option
GKsu version 2.0.2

Usage: gksudo [-u <user>] [options] <command>

Comment: Ok, `gksudo` parses its parameters differently than `sudo`. Try `gksudo -- sh -x /usr/bin/tksuite`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ju2yEBuJ

Comment: As I thought. I'll edit my answer to workaround that defect.